# Capture IPhone screen from MAC via USB without JailBreaking

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there any way to capture screen of iphone device which is connected to mac via USB.

I want to do something similar to xcode ->organizer -> device ->capture Screen.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I quit thinking about using this way - simply because it seems to nearly never work for some unknown reasons.

Save your time for more important things and do your screenshots the easy way.

Just hold the home button on the device and then press the on/off button - the screen will fade from white to normal and you'll find the screenshot in the devices camera roll (image library)

Now you can easily access the screenshots via USB as if you took a normal photo.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My purpose is not getting screen shots. i want to access my device remotely on my mac. I am looking some possible way to do this. I am able to capture screen from device and send to desktop using UIGetScreenImage private API. but it works on jailbroken device.. I am looking some other alternative like tethering device via USB and capturing screen. Is there any way to get device details from mac(device name, file system etc..) once we connect the device via USB?

Comment: Well I guess Apple won't be so happy if you do it via USB - seems to me like jailbreaking is the only way of getting this done... but I might be wrong on that one.

Comment: ...perhaps you should investigate on tethering devices via WiFi like many other Apps do - this semms to be allowed even though I never tried myself.